# Dynamic DLL which statically links a library

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am writing a shared library which depends on ODBC.  I would like to statically link the ODBC library so that a user of my library does not need the ODBC library installed.  However, when my dll is linked, it appears to dynamically link to the odbc library instead of statically linking to it (this is verified using dependency walker).  Is it possible to statically link a library into a dll?

I am working in visual studio 2010.  I use `#pragma comment(lib, "odbc32.lib")` and have verified that the library is a static library not an imports library.  What else could be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure odbc32.lib is *not* an import library?

Comment: Windows components don't usually have static libraries.  ODBC might be an exception, but I don't think so.  Certainly the `odbc32.lib` in the Windows 7 SDK is an import library.  What exactly did you do to verify that the library you're looking at is a static library?

Comment: Also, is `odbc32.dll` an optional component in the first place?  I don't see anything obviously related in my Windows Features control panel ... perhaps all Windows machines have this library so you don't need to worry?

Comment: I am using `dumpbin /exports "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\odbc32.lib"`.  Is that the incorrect use of the dumpbin tool?

Comment: Harry, good point about odbc being a standard component.  You are probably right about that.  I was also having issues linking some of the SQL server driver libraries to use with odbc but, given the previous comments, it sounds like that is not the correct use of the libraries.

Comment: odbc.lib is the import library for the DLL.  Rather the opposite of what you want.  You can't get what you want, it isn't available as a static link library.  Much the same as about every other operating system library you link with.  Hard to innovate on an operating system when you're stuck in static library hell.  You have the Solemn Promise from Microsoft that they make it *their* problem.  They have a good track-record of getting that right.  If they get it wrong then there's a sympathetic voice on the other end of the phone call.  Not yours to make.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need (and can't get) a static library; `odbc32` is part of the operating system, and, like all other Windows components, must be dynamically linked.

Answer (score 0):

Using visual studio 2015/2017 with console / win32 App it works with:

**`#pragma comment(lib, "odbc32.lib")`**

just after #include....

Comment: As already discussed in the contents, that's an import library, not a static library.  The version of Visual Studio makes no difference.